# plot data differences

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
data12 = {
   {1, 981.946, 978.783, 978.783},
   {2, 813.948, 810.783, 810.667},
   {3, 743.422, 743.447, 744.062},
   {4, 715.382, 715.478, 715.326},
   {5, 690.345, 696.075, 691.664},
   {6, 862.126, 870.902, 860.371}
};
```

I want to make a `ListLinePlot` using the first row element (the index) as the X coordinate, and for the Y coordinate, the difference between the second and third value in row (generally speaking, the difference between two generic columns). How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

=== EDIT ===

I've found this solution:

```
ListLinePlot[{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]} & /@ data12]
```

Is it a good solution, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thus, you want to completely ignore the fourth and last column?

Comment: No, I want to choose columns, but I've asked a simpler question because then I want to generalize it by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to map the pure function `{#[[1]],#[[3]]-#[[2]]}&` onto the data before calling `ListLinePlot`.

```
data12 = {
   {1, 981.946, 978.783, 978.783},
   {2, 813.948, 810.783, 810.667},
   {3, 743.422, 743.447, 744.062},
   {4, 715.382, 715.478, 715.326},
   {5, 690.345, 696.075, 691.664},
   {6, 862.126, 870.902, 860.371}
};
ListLinePlot[{#[[1]],#[[3]]-#[[2]]}& /@ data12]
```

Comment: I've found the same solution... Nice...

Answer (score 6):

Your method can be made more concise by using `Slot` (`#`, `#2`, etc.) and `Apply` at level 1 (`@@@`):

```
ListLinePlot[{#, #2 - #3} & @@@ data12]
```

I see this was recommended by J.M. in an earlier comment.

This is also faster than your method:

```
dat = RandomChoice[data12, 500000];

{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]} & /@ dat // Timing // First

{#1, #2 - #3} & @@@ dat // Timing // First
```

> 0.53
>
> 0.328

The method recommended by PlatoManiac is much faster still:

```
Transpose[{#1, #3 - #2} & @@ Transpose[dat]] // Timing // First
```

> 0.078

Equally fast in another method using `Part`:

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2]] - #[[All, 3]]} &@dat] // Timing // First
```

> 0.078

Answer (score 5):

While not a faster solution, you can also try using a replacement rule (which can sometimes lead to more "readable" code):

```
ListLinePlot[data12 /. {c1_, c2_, c3_, c4_} -> {c1, c3 - c2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way can be operating on the column vectors. `Transpose` gives columns then we use the pure function for the subtraction and a second `Transpose` brings the result into a form required by `ListLinePlot`. Notice that the column numbers of `data12` are reflected similarly in the `Slot` sequence numbering.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@({#1, #3 - #2} & @@ Transpose[data12])]
```

[image]

BR

Comment: Too complicated. Try `ListLinePlot[{#1, #3 - #2} & @@@ data12]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thx! An eyeopener indeed..